# How to create unique column in registration validator for two different tables

Tags: laravel

I'm creating two different registration (for admin and user). But the username->unique in the validator is only for table users.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'min:3'],
        'middlename' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'min:3'],
        'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'min:3'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'min:3', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

validate unique username for user registration from the users table and validate unique username for admin registration from the admins table.

Comment: Do you have a select or radio button option which you use to know if the user is an admin or a normal user?

Comment: @nakov the default registration page is for users. Im trying to make another registration form for admins in the admin dashboard.

Comment: you will need to pass a hidden value, or get the request uri to determine if the user that is registering is a normal user or an admin. Then you can make a if condition where you set the last item of the username if it should be set to `unique:users` or `unique:admins`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [route name](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getName) or something similar, from the [current request](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) to determine which rules have to get used.

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $route = Request::route()->getName();

    $rules = [
        'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'min:3'],
        'middlename' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'min:3'],
        'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'min:3'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
    ];

    // whatever your route name or identifier to differentiate between
    // user and admin registration may be.
    if ($route === 'registration.user') {
        $rules = $rules + [
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'min:3', 'unique:users'],
        ];
    }

    return Validator::make($data, $rules);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Validator should only validate data, it's bad to couple it with concepts about routes etc...

I would create a custom Validator class which will take a table name as parameter.

Then you can instantiate that validator with the correct table parameters in your controller (which will be aware about route, request etc...)